# Performance test batch based Java Micro Service

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a batch based micro service that runs every after a particular interval through a chronos job for which I have to performance test. This micro service doesn't return any response but downloads zip files from Amazon S3, extract them and uploads the individual files from the zip to Amazon S3. I work on JMETER to performance test Web applications. Can I use JMeter for perf testing this batch based micro service? If yes, what would I have to do?

Comment: Do you download it locally to where your "microservice" is running, and process there? Or you just trigger some service at the remote location ( say, on AWS) that does the job for you, and then you're checking the status somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use JMeter for this, take a look at:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - to mimic downloads and uploads
- [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener - to store downloaded zip files
- [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) - to unzip the downloaded files

Check our [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for detailed information on JMeter configuration for file operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can't load test this service, because it has no particular HTTP endpoint. There is no load on this service since it's not being hit by any user.

You should use production monitoring instead to track any performance issue while the service is running.